# Android: saving info for trial application

Tags: android

I want to save some info regarding a trial version an application.

I want this info to be persistent in order to detect if the user removed the application and installed it again after the trial expiry.

what is the best place to store such info

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the times the solution to this problem is to keep an server side check,

But if you dont want to involve a server its better to give some limited functionality in your trail app and full in the paid version.

There are other methods too like Time Trial but again they all depends on persistent data so they also fails if the user uninstalls and installs again your applucation

Comment: I agree. if the user hard resets the application, he can again use your trial app again. the best idea would be to get the device ID and store it on server to track usage. but be careful while handling the private data.

Comment: @Sheikh Aman- Yeah forgot to mention that thanks for adding that

Comment: What about using the settings content provider: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html to store such info ?

Comment: they can be used to store key/value pair settings

Comment: Look I dont know what you are saying but if you think that your idea by using key/values is correct then gave it a shot by trying it if that works then post your method and mark it as answer but FYI Settings page is also accessed by user

Comment: I think the solution is a server side check by the devide id

Comment: @ingsaurabh: "its better to give some limited functionality in your trail app and full in the paid version." Is that done by publishing two versions of my app? Could you help @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725501/is-a-trial-like-behavior-possible-in-android-apps ?

Answer (score 1):

Store it in external file.

it wont be deleted after user uninstalled the app.

but

Serverside check by Device ID is the good way ..

Comment: but a more advanced user can delete that too

Comment: and the external file can be on the SD Card which can be formatted

Comment: or can find it and then modify it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the same "problem" at the moment (offline solution for trial time expired apps):

My findings: There is no way to ensure that a user *never* can reinstall & reuse a (time) trial app but there is a way to 'nearly' prevent it:

1. Use shared preferences / a database / file saved on internal storage containing the install timestamp.
2. If the device has an external storage card (most devices have) also save the timestamp on the sd card.

The only possiblity to use your application also after expiring is if the user 1. clears app data on the phone and 2. finds the timestamp file on the sd card and also kills this one.

If he "just kills" the first or second check the killed one can be restored on next app start.