# Android free app limit usage lock out

Tags: android

I want to release a trial version of my Android App that can only run for a fixed number of days before it disables itself. What techniques could be used that would provide reasonable protection and achieve this?

I am hoping to avoid the need for a licensing server. But if I do need one does anyone know of any open source license servers that they would recommend. If not open source then any that are reasonably priced?

Thank you for your kind response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android makes it pretty hard to reliably resist pirating. You basically can't trust the device, pretty much need to have a call on startup to your server with the unique ID that authorizes or rejects the user. If most of the functionality relies on some server of yours, then you can make the app much more resistant to pirating by requiring a valid device ID on startup to get some sort of auth token, which your other RPCs can then use to authenticate the app.

Answer (score 2):

I have a suggestion, although I do not know how effective it will be against someone who is very determined to get your app for free.

You could have a check that happens on startup of your app.  If it is the first time the user has opened the app, then you take note of the time, and save it into a private preference of the app.  If it is not the first time the user has opened the app, check to see if it is still within the valid data/time range from the initial time you saved to preferences.  If valid, continue as normal, if not, display some message asking them to download the full version.

Again, I am not suggesting this is the best idea, or that it is even completely secure (as I do not know if anyone or any app could have access to those preferences).  But I do think that it would be a cheap solution and easy to implement.

Comment: Wiping the app data would reset the preference would it not? That would make it ineffective at stopping someone from using the app based on a time function.

Comment: I figured something would be bad about that solution.  It is just the same as when some applications provide a trial period based on an email, you just need to get a new email.  But it is usually enough to keep most honest...

Answer (score 2):

I had answered this question previously might be helpful [Android: saving info for trial application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064993/android-saving-info-for-trial-application/5065085#5065085)