# Is a Trial-like behavior possible in android apps

Tags: android, xamarin.android, licensing

I'm new to Android developement (I know very basic stuffs), and there is a chance that soon I'll be tasked with porting a WP7 app to Android (fortunately, I can use MonoDroid...).

Now that app has a trial functionality ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967558%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)), which for WP7 means that I can check whether the user bought it (so I can enable additional features inside the app) or downloaded the free edition. I do not want the trial to expire, I want a "free edition" of my app to be limited to certain features.

**Is there anything similiar for Android?** (And can it be done on MonoDroid?)

I've looked at Google Licensing Service, but I don't see how that helps me.

Comment: To your first comment dont store it on server store it in local db file in device and based on that unlock app feature in case user re-install the app then check for in app and if its already purchased store the the value again in local db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for two apps solution. One **"real"** application, which contains all the functionality. Second **"key"** application which only check licensing.

First application will check if the **key** application is installed. If the check is positive then display full content, enable all features. If the key application is missing the application behaves like free version.

It is also very important to check if the private key that signed both applications is the same. Without this check someone might create their own **key** application and unlock your functionality. To do so consider this snippet, which I took from this blog: http://www.yoki.org/2010/07/31/creating-a-freepaid-app-pair-for-the-android-market/

```
protected boolean isProInstalled(Context context) {
  // the packagename of the 'key' app
  String proPackage = "org.yoki.android.pkgname";

  // get the package manager
  final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
  // get a list of installed packages
  List<PackageInfo> list = 
         pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_DISABLED_COMPONENTS);

  // let's iterate through the list
  Iterator<PackageInfo> i = list.iterator();
  while(i.hasNext()) {
    PackageInfo p = i.next();
    // check if proPackage is in the list AND whether that package is signed
    //  with the same signature as THIS package
    if((p.packageName.equals(proPackage)) &&
       (pm.checkSignatures(context.getPackageName(), p.packageName) == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

This approach gives you few advantages in flexibility:

- separate paid areas. You can assign sets of features to different **key** applications. eg. app key1 unlocks additional game levels a1,a2,a3 and app key2 unlocks levels b1,b2
- time licensing - instead of only checking the existence of **key** application. You can query it to check if the licence is still valid. That way you can achieve time licences.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way for you would be to use [in-app purchases](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html)

Comment: So I publish the app for free, and if they "upgrade" in-app, I note it on my server that they can use the advanced features, and everytime they want to access the feature, I check online? Is there an offline way? (if I simply write a file, what is to stop them to manually creating that file?)

Comment: Yes, you publish it for free and they upgrade their app. You won't need an own server for this, as it will be stored with their Google Account.
You have to store the purchase in a database, so people don't have to be online every time they want to use the app.
However, if the user reinstalls the app, the purchase is not lost so they don't have to buy it again.

Comment: 1. Where to store that database? Won't an SQLite db be deleted with my app? 2. If I do have a server (for other purposes than purchasing) can I "ask" Google if a certain person has bought my upgrade?

Comment: 1. Yes, it will be deleted, but you can check if the user has bought your upgrade on first start and restore the purchase. See http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html for implementation examples. 2. You can optionally send the purchases to your own server or use Googles Checkout API (I would rather recommend going for the API). Anyway all your purchases are listed at your Google Checkout Merchant site.

Comment: Can you link something relevant about the second part? :) Btw, thanks for all the help, will accept answer as soon as I get a chance to actually try it out!

Comment: Sure =) The Checkout API is explained at http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API.html , but you should first concentrate on implementing In App purchases. The link I posted in the Answer gives a brief overview, have a look at the PurchaseObserver, as this is the one that could also post purchases to your server.